# What are the side effects of changing MySQL `character_set_server`?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, character-set

I am having some strange issues with character sets on my system. After digging through all kinds of settings, I found a discrepancy in my character set settings.

When I run `show variables like 'char%';` I get:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

1. Are there any side effects to changing the the `character_set_server` variable?

   - Could it possibly affect what `character set` a connection will use when talking with the database?
   - Could it possibly alter the existing data in any way?

From my understanding, it looks like all it does is set the character set for you when creating a new database if you don't specify a charset. Is that really all it does?

*Source:* https://www.blueboxcloud.com/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell

Answer (score 0):

You've stumbled onto one of the imponderables of MySQL's default configuration. To quote from the documentation on [Character Set Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-configuration.html):

> ...when character_set_system differs from character_set_server or
>   character_set_client, and you input characters manually (as database
>   object identifiers, column values, or both), these may be displayed
>   incorrectly in output from the client or the output itself may be
>   formatted incorrectly. In such cases, starting the mysql client with
>   --default-character-set=system_character_set—that is, setting the client character set to match the system character set—should fix the
>   problem.

To distill, *not* changing the value of `character_set_server` will almost certainly eventually cause you problems if you use Unicode characters outside the base `ISO-latin-1` character set.

Comment: Any idea what the documentation you posted means when it says `you input characters manually`?

Comment: Not sure how this applies, but I found some text in the documentation that lead me to believe that `character_set_server` is kinda useless if you set the DB charset, which I have done.

```The server character set and collation are used as default values if the database character set and collation are not specified in CREATE DATABASE statements. They have no other purpose.```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-server.html

Comment: I ran into trouble when I entered accented characters through the `mysql` client - PHP `json_encode()` b!+ched at me about "malformed utf8" - and I understand others have had the same problem from Workbench or phpmyadmin. Changing `character_set_server` fixed the problem.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax - that's surprising.  The 3 settings changed by `SET NAMES` (or equivalent) are more relevant.